# How to view file inside html? File can be received from node js server

Tags: html, node.js, file, iframe, view

How to return a file from node js and view inside html using javascript. file types can be .pdf, xls, ppt, ppx, doc, docx, jpeg, png, jpg,  bmp .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Consider displaying the document to the user in an HTML viewer component. For example, the [LEADTOOLS HTML5 Document Viewer](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document/document-viewer) can be used with NodeJS to accomplish this. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)